# How to use Google Colab on local machine

Tags: local, google-colaboratory

I'm working on deep-learning projects with Google Colaboratory. Because there isn't enough storage space on Google Cloud for my training datasets, I try to use Colab on my local machine.

I followed these tips provided by Google to connect Colab with my computer:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

but I failed at Step 4. The Colab page raised:

> Unable to connect to the runtime.

Meanwhile my Ubuntu terminal raised:

> [W 22:41:53.396 NotebookApp]Forbidden
>
> [W 22:41:53.396 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs (10.133.6.71) 1.45ms referer=None

How can I successfully connect Colab with my pc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your invocation of `jupyter` needs particular arguments to authorize Colab to speak to it. Did you start `jupyter` with the args indicated?

```
jupyter notebook \
  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
  --port=8888 \
  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

Given that a 403 is a permissions error, I suspect you might be missing the  `NotebookApp.allow_origin` option.

Comment: That's exactly the problem! These command lines failed to pass args to my  jupyter, so I config these args by editing the jupyter_notebook_config.py file. It finally works. Many thanks to you :-D

Comment: @ZhangYushu this command should open the colab site, correct? I still see it launches my local jupyter though, `serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/me/Sites/myproject`any suggestion  ?

Comment: I found on firefox is working by enabling websocket via https, however on chrome it keeps giving 403 error. I refer to `https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html`- any idea to solve it on chrome ?

Comment: I have established a local runtime connection to my localhost on my system. Is it possible that I can share this runtime with another computer in my network? I tried using IP but Google Colab doesn't let me use other than localhost.